# OpenFileDialog with file create option

Tags: c#, wpf-controls

```
Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog ofd = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
ofd.Filter = "log Files | *.log";
if (ofd.ShowDialog() == true)
    LogFileName = ofd.FileName;
```

I have openfiledialog with filter option which shows only the .log files. How can I disable this filter to allow the user to create a new file (.txt) if there is no .log file exists.

Comment: The file existence check could be skipped: `ofd.CheckFileExists = false;`. This allows the dialog to accept any file name, including *.txt, but you still have to create the file yourself afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

There is a special dialog for this case. It is called `SaveFileDialog`. I suggest you use this dialog for your purpose:

```
using Microsoft.Win32;

(...)

SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();

if(sfd.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    (...)    
}
```

Comment: it is only for saving, but if the exist i need to open the same

Comment: Assuming there will be only one (.log) file
Say if user selects the path ex:(c:\test) and if the .log file exist then it should return c:\test\xyz.log.
if file not exist then in the same control user should specify the file name and it should be saved in the path in .log extension.
The below is the code :

Comment: So does the user need to be queried to select a file or a folder? Because there would be another dialog for that the `OpenFolderDialog`.